# How can I ensure vfprintf has the proper number of arguments?

Tags: c

I have a variable-argument function in C that looks roughly like this:

```
void log(const char * format, ...) {

  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  vfprintf( stderr, format, args );
  va_end(args);
  exit(1);
}
```

I was able crash my app by callilng it like this,

`log("%s %d", 1);`

because the function was missing an argument. Is there a way to determine an argument is missing at runtime?

Comment: You can probably crash your app just as well with `printf("%s %d", 1);`. How do you expect to prevent that from happening? (The point: if someone decides to write incorrect code, why should they expect it to work?)

Comment: My compiler (GCC) warns me about insufficient arguments in that case.

Comment: Then see Roland Illig's answer for about all you can do, but note that, if people write code incorrectly, it will probably crash, and there's nothing you can do about it short of using a safer (and more restrictive, and potentially slower) language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there would be any standard mechanism for determining that at runtime.  The parameters after the format specifier are simply values on the stack.  For example, if a format specifier indicated a 4-byte integer was next, there would be no way of knowing if the next 4 bytes on the stack were an integer or just whatever happened to be on the stack from a previous call.

Comment: Thanks. This concisely explains why I can't *really* check. (I was unsure what the actual variable-arguments mechanism was, but knowing this I can see why.)

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't. But when you compile your code with gcc, you should add the options `-Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Os`. This will enable lots of warnings, and when you annotate your function with `__attribute__(__printf__, 2, 3)` or something similar (I don't remember  the exact syntax), a warning for exactly your case should appear.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html for the exact syntax. It's really `__atttribute__((__format__(__printf__, 1, 2)))`.

Comment: Your syntax is almost right, but `__attribute__` uses double parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the info. At the moment I'm aiming for portability, so I probably won't end up using this. +1 anyway though. :)

Comment: Concerning portability. You can define a macro `attribute_printf(fmt, args)` that generates the annotation when used in gcc, and an empty string otherwise. Then you can use that macro, plus it aids as an annotation to the code, so you need to write less comments.

Comment: I like that suggestion. Perhaps I'll do that after all.

Comment: Then have a look at http://www.google.de/codesearch?q=define.%2A__attribute__.%2Aformat for prior work. Maybe there is other useful code nearby, and you can see how others did the check for GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Nope there isn't, C will allow you to shoot yourself in the foot just like that.

Comment: Correct, but that doesn't mean you can't add checks yourself. (Not my downvote though)

Comment: @delnan: It does exactly mean that. There is __no way__ to check for it __at runtime__. The second you read past the end of `va_list` your application is Undefined Behaviour and C is allowed to crash all day long.

Comment: @delnan - How would you add a runtime check for varargs? _Perhaps_ you could do it with some _serious_ C99 macro hacking wizardry, but it'd be one of the most hideous things imaginable, and you'd almost certainly have the arguments multiple-evaluated.